# Error while building a linux kernel for xiaomi device

Tags: linux, build, kernel, xiaomi

While building kernel i get error:

```
In file included from ../arch/arm64/kernel/sys.c:27:
../include/linux/syscalls.h:195:18: warning: ‘sys_arm64_personality’ alias between functions of incompatible types ‘long int(unsigned int)’ and ‘long int(long int)’ [-Wattribute-alias=]
error, forbidden warning: syscalls.h:195
make[2]: *** [../scripts/Makefile.build:339: arch/arm64/kernel/sys.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/home/z/kernel_dev/kernel_olive_lolz-stock/Makefile:1100: arch/arm64/kernel] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Full log in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KqG3gEvL).
[Kernel source](https://github.com/Ghost-ate-your-brains/kernel_olive_lolz/tree/stock), what i try to build.
And it's not [official source](http://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/tree/olive-p-oss), because the are broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can silence "attribute-alias" warning by adding following line in kernel/Makefile to fix it:

KBUILD_CFLAGS  += $(call cc-disable-warning, attribute-alias)